# Left join on Postgresql and QGIS returning different results?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I'm using the following expression to join to layers and produce a virtual layer.

```
select * from table1 left join table2 on table1.field1=table2.field2
```

When I do it in Qgis, my virtual layer doesn't have the values from the joined table, whereas if I query exactly the same expression on pgadmin, it will return all values.
Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: This seems to work as expected for me, as long as I don't include the layers as "embedded layers" in the "Create Virtual Layer" dialog, since the layers I'm joining are already in my project. If I do include them, I get zero results returned. Are you seeing results returned but without the columns from table2 present? Because I definitely see columns from my table2.

Comment: My problem with embedded layers doesn't manifest if the layers are OGR layers, like shapefiles - it happens if they are memory layers which I'd created for testing. Which is interesting...

Comment: Indeed. My layers are both Postgresql tables. If I don't embed the layers, the values are filled in the columns. It's a pity it won't update if I opt out of the embedding, but at least it works that way.

Comment: Forgot to mention that it only worked because I confgured a join between the two layers. So, nevermind doing the join through SQL, better just have a join configured.